# Restructure geom_tile ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a 4x4 geom_tile plot where the upper right cell contains an additional 4x4 cell.  I am wanting the plot to appear as it does below.

[image: Desired output visuals]

The positions are listed inside the cells for clarity, however, the code makes the data value corresponding with the position placed in the cell.  The sample code I provided currently produces this:

[image: Current ggplot output]

I am not able to manipulate the data values in terms of position (values for x and y cannot be changed) and the cell containing additional breakdown will not always be in the upper right so a solution that does not hardcode this location in would be appreciated.

If this is possible I would greatly appreciate any assistance you can provide!

```
x <- c(0,0,1,0.5,0.5,1,1)
y <- c(0,1,0,0.5,1,0.5,1)
data_val <- sample(0:100, 7)
alldata <-data.frame(x, y, data_val)


    ggplot(data= alldata, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_tile(colour = "black") + 
    geom_text(aes(label = data_val),colour="white")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires a slight change to your notation, so that x and y correctly locate the centre of each square, and an additional width parameter (which with this system really only depends on whether x and y are even or odd).  For other quartered squares, use -1/+1 instead of 3/5 as appropriate.

```
x <- c(0,0,4,3,3,5,5)
y <- c(0,4,0,3,5,3,5)
w <- ifelse(x%%2==0, 4, 2)
data_val <- sample(0:100, 7)
alldata <- data.frame(x, y, w, data_val)

ggplot(data= alldata, aes(x=x, y=y, width=w, height=w)) +
  geom_tile(fill = "white", color="black") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = data_val), colour="black") +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Comment: Andrew, could you please further explain the line `w <- ifelse(x%%2==0, 4, 2)` so that I can adapt it in different situations?  I have data that has different x and y positions, different dimensions (3x3, 4x4 and 5x5 instead of the 2x2 that I gave as a sample) etc. and I would like to understand the logic of that line so that I can modify it to accommodate a wide variety of inputs.

Comment: Yes - w (the width of a square) is either 2 or 4.  The big squares are centred on even numbers (`x%%2==0`) and the small squares are centred on odd numbers.  It should work for larger grids as long as you use this coordinate system.

Comment: The way that the data is collected, there is not a guarantee that the numbers will fall on "pretty" numbers.  For example, I have a data set that is a 5x5 with `x = -0.84, -0.42, 0, 0.42, 0.84` and y=`-0.71, -0.355, 0, 0.355, 0.71`.  There is then an additional 5x5 matrix centered around the point (0.84, 0.71).How would I structure the line of code defining width so that it is able to handle a wide variety of positional input like that?  I realize that is a pretty in depth question for a comment on a post so I can ask a new question if additional detail is required to convey my problem.

Comment: My trick won't work if the smaller grid is 5x5, or if your `x` and `y` intervals are different. In that case you will also need a separate `height` column and will need to find a way of setting `width` and `height` equal to the large x or y interval for the main squares, and those values over 5 (or whatever) for the small ones.

Comment: If you know which are the large and small squares, then separate them, sort by `x` (or `y`), and then `max(diff(x))` will give the appropriate width to use. If you don't know which are the small squares it is more tricky, but `sort` and `diff` will get you some of the way!

Comment: I have been working with what you provided throughout the day and have a few more problems that I have run in to, the first of which is how to adapt your solution to cells that have other than a 2x2 for an additional detail cell.  I have attempted a solution that does not break having a 2x2, but also does not allow for a 5x5 to be used.  I am posting a new question that I would greatly appreciate your input on.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814267/variable-size-of-geom-tile-plot