# geom_tiles : multivariable histogram with variable bin sizes

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, multivariate-partition

I have d-dimensional hyperrectangles defined by a minimum point and a maximum points. I have weights on theese rectangles and they form a partition of [0,1]^d. How can i plot a facetted geom_tiles that would show me every 2 dimensional projection of this partition ?

```
x = list(minimum_points = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.419352004803182, 0.419352004803182, 0.419352004803182, 0.419352004803182, 
0.419352004803182, 0.419352004803182, 0.419352004803182, 0.419352004803182, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0353348860019376, 0.0353348860019376, 
0.0353348860019376, 0.0353348860019376, 0.0353348860019376, 0.0353348860019376, 
0.0353348860019376, 0.0353348860019376, 0.0353348860019376, 0.0353348860019376, 
0.0353348860019376, 0.0354309314611505, 0.0354309314611505, 0.0354309314611505, 
0.0354309314611505, 0.0354309314611505, 0.0354309314611505, 0.0354309314611505, 
0.0354309314611505, 0.0353348860019376, 0.0353348860019376, 0.0353348860019376, 
0.0353348860019376, 0.0353348860019376, 0.190285344706225, 0.190285344706225, 
0.190285344706225, 0.190285344706225, 0.190285344706225, 0.190285344706225, 
0.190285344706225, 0.190285344706225, 0.190285344706225, 0.222681715801928, 
0.222681715801928, 0.222681715801928, 0.222681715801928, 0.190285344706225, 
0.190285344706225, 0.0353348860019376, 0.0353348860019376, 0.0353348860019376, 
0.0353348860019376, 0.0353348860019376, 0.0353348860019376, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0968321963495523, 0.0968321963495523, 
0.0968321963495523, 0.0968321963495523, 0.0968321963495523, 0.0968321963495523, 
0.0968321963495523, 0.0968321963495523, 0.0968321963495523, 0.21505376344086, 
0.21505376344086, 0.21505376344086, 0.21505376344086, 0.21505376344086, 
0.21505376344086, 0.21505376344086, 0.21505376344086, 0.0968321963495523, 
0.0968321963495523, 0.0968321963495523, 0.0968321963495523, 0.0968321963495523, 
0.0968321963495523, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.82789108509519, 0.82789108509519, 0.82789108509519, 
0.82789108509519, 0.82789108509519, 0.82789108509519, 0.82789108509519, 
0.82789108509519, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.865298312421161, 
0.865298312421161, 0.865298312421161, 0.865298312421161, 0.865298312421161, 
0.865298312421161, 0.865298312421161, 0.865298312421161, 0.865298312421161, 
0.865298312421161, 0.913338086705426, 0.913338086705426, 0.913338086705426, 
0.913338086705426, 0.913338086705426, 0.913338086705426, 0.913338086705426, 
0.913338086705426, 0.865298312421161, 0.865298312421161, 0.865298312421161, 
0.865298312421161, 0.865298312421161, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.694970507094714, 0.694970507094714, 
0.694970507094714, 0.694970507094714, 0.694970507094714, 0.694970507094714, 
0.694970507094714, 0.694970507094714, 0.694970507094714, 0.929741242956996, 
0.929741242956996, 0.929741242956996, 0.929741242956996, 0.929741242956996, 
0.929741242956996, 0.929741242956996, 0.929741242956996, 0.694970507094714, 
0.694970507094714, 0.694970507094714, 0.694970507094714, 0.694970507094714, 
0.694970507094714, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.548419213078966, 
0.548419213078966, 0.548419213078966, 0.548419213078966, 0.548419213078966, 
0.548419213078966, 0.548419213078966, 0.548419213078966, 0.5, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.255374814781996, 0.255374814781996, 0.255374814781996, 
0.255374814781996, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.255374814781996, 0.255374814781996, 
0.255374814781996, 0.255374814781996, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.398483289450429, 
0.398483289450429, 0.398483289450429, 0.398483289450429, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.161209591513803, 0.161209591513803, 0.161209591513803, 
0.161209591513803, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.161209591513803, 0.161209591513803, 
0.161209591513803, 0.161209591513803, 0, 0.161290323203977, 0.161290323203977, 
0.161290323203977, 0.161290323203977, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.161290323203977, 
0.161290323203977, 0.161290323203977, 0.161290323203977, 0.161290323203977, 
0.161290323203977, 0.161290323203977, 0.161290323203977, 0.161290323203977, 
0.161290323203977, 0.161290323203977, 0, 0, 0.398483289450429, 
0.398483289450429, 0.398483289450429, 0.398483289450429, 0, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.832337120350762, 0.832337120350762, 
0.832337120350762, 0.832337120350762, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.709677419354839, 0.709677419354839, 0.709677419354839, 0.709677419354839, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.709677419354839, 0.709677419354839, 0.709677419354839, 
0.709677419354839, 0.5, 0.5, 0.832337120350762, 0.832337120350762, 
0.832337120350762, 0.832337120350762, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.283397163276916, 0.283397163276916, 0.283397163276916, 0.283397163276916, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.283397163276916, 0.283397163276916, 0.283397163276916, 
0.283397163276916, 0, 0.442671222839882, 0.442671222839882, 0.442671222839882, 
0.442671222839882, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.340698528466384, 0.340698528466384, 
0.340698528466384, 0.340698528466384, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.340698528466384, 
0.340698528466384, 0.340698528466384, 0.340698528466384, 0, 0.442671222839882, 
0.442671222839882, 0.442671222839882, 0.442671222839882, 0, 0, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.685576901737226, 0.685576901737226, 
0.685576901737226, 0.685576901737226, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.663570349214972, 0.663570349214972, 0.663570349214972, 0.663570349214972, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.663570349214972, 0.663570349214972, 0.663570349214972, 
0.663570349214972, 0.5, 0.5, 0.685576901737226, 0.685576901737226, 
0.685576901737226, 0.685576901737226, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.669183378958155, 
0.669183378958155, 0.669183378958155, 0.669183378958155, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.669183378958155, 0.669183378958155, 0.669183378958155, 
0.669183378958155, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.379031077580214, 0.379031077580214, 
0, 0, 0.379031077580214, 0.379031077580214, 0, 0, 0.379031077580214, 
0.379031077580214, 0, 0, 0.379031077580214, 0.379031077580214, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.967729256836288, 0.967729256836288, 0.5, 0.5, 0.967729256836288, 
0.967729256836288, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.826609713837449, 0.826609713837449, 
0.967610625409862, 0.967610625409862, 0.826609713837449, 0.826609713837449, 
0.967610625409862, 0.967610625409862, 0.826609713837449, 0.826609713837449, 
0.967610625409862, 0.967610625409862, 0.826609713837449, 0.826609713837449, 
0.967610625409862, 0.967610625409862, 0.826609713837449, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.826609713837449, 0.826609713837449, 0.5, 0.5, 0.826609713837449, 
0.826609713837449, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.722675196396205, 0.722675196396205, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.722675196396205, 0.722675196396205, 0.826609713837449, 
0.826609713837449, 0.967729256836288, 0.967729256836288, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.967729256836288, 0.967729256836288, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.897477061307942, 0.897477061307942, 0.5, 0.5, 0.897477061307942, 
0.897477061307942, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.741935483870968, 0.741935483870968, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.741935483870968, 0.741935483870968, 0.5, 0.5, 0.741935483870968, 
0.741935483870968, 0.5, 0.5, 0.741935483870968, 0.741935483870968, 
0.897477061307942, 0.897477061307942, 0.5, 0.5, 0.897477061307942, 
0.897477061307942, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.032538108376287, 0.032538108376287, 
0.0967749770900052, 0.0967749770900052, 0.032538108376287, 0.032538108376287, 
0.0967749770900052, 0.0967749770900052, 0.032538108376287, 0.032538108376287, 
0.0967749770900052, 0.0967749770900052, 0.032538108376287, 0.032538108376287, 
0.0967749770900052, 0.0967749770900052, 0.032538108376287, 0, 
0, 0.032538108376287, 0.032538108376287, 0, 0, 0.032538108376287, 
0.032538108376287, 0.0647887222047812, 0.0647887222047812, 0.032538108376287, 
0.032538108376287, 0.0647887222047812, 0.0647887222047812, 0.032538108376287, 
0.032538108376287, 0.0647887222047812, 0.0647887222047812, 0.032538108376287, 
0.032538108376287, 0.0647887222047812, 0.0647887222047812, 0.032538108376287, 
0, 0, 0.032538108376287, 0.032538108376287, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 
0.322580324979444, 0.322580324979444, 0, 0, 0.322580324979444, 
0.322580324979444, 0, 0, 0, 0.106364539814871, 0.106364539814871, 
0, 0, 0.106364539814871, 0.106364539814871, 0, 0, 0.106364539814871, 
0.106364539814871, 0, 0, 0.106364539814871, 0.106364539814871, 
0.322580324979444, 0.322580324979444, 0, 0, 0.322580324979444, 
0.322580324979444, 0.5, 0.5, 0.548419212162221, 0.548419212162221, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.548419212162221, 0.548419212162221, 0.5, 0.5, 0.548419212162221, 
0.548419212162221, 0.5, 0.5, 0.548419212162221, 0.548419212162221, 
0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.526892491080578, 0.5, 0.526892491080578, 0.5, 
0.526892491080578, 0.5, 0.526892491080578, 0.5, 0.526892491080578, 
0.5, 0.526892491080578, 0.5, 0.526892491080578, 0.5, 0.526892491080578, 
0, 0.0353381808372436, 0, 0.0353381808372436, 0, 0.0353381808372436, 
0, 0.0353381808372436, 0, 0.0353381808372436, 0.190286155838143, 
0.0353381808372436, 0.0354342216918294, 0.0353381808372436, 0.0354342216918294, 
0.0353381808372436, 0.0354342216918294, 0.0353381808372436, 0.0354342216918294, 
0.0353381808372436, 0.0354342216918294, 0.0353381808372436, 0.0354342216918294, 
0.0353381808372436, 0.0354342216918294, 0.0353381808372436, 0.0354342216918294, 
0.190286155838143, 0.0353381808372436, 0.190286155838143, 0.0353381808372436, 
0.190286155838143, 0.0353381808372436, 0.190286155838143, 0.0353381808372436, 
0.190286155838143, 0.0353381808372436, 0.190286155838143, 0.225826581007251, 
0.190286155838143, 0.225826581007251, 0.190286155838143, 0.225826581007251, 
0.190286155838143, 0.225826581007251, 0.0353381808372436, 0.190286155838143, 
0, 0.0353381808372436, 0, 0.0353381808372436, 0, 0.0353381808372436, 
0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.0967747030398799, 0, 0.0967747030398799, 0, 
0.0967747030398799, 0, 0.0967747030398799, 0, 0.0967747030398799, 
0.21505376344086, 0.0967747030398799, 0.21505376344086, 0.0967747030398799, 
0.21505376344086, 0.0967747030398799, 0.21505376344086, 0.0967747030398799, 
0.21505376344086, 0.0967747030398799, 0.21505376344086, 0.0967747030398799, 
0.21505376344086, 0.0967747030398799, 0.21505376344086, 0, 0.0967747030398799, 
0, 0.0967747030398799, 0, 0.0967747030398799, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.944702130460738, 
0.5, 0.747533402579888, 0.5, 0.747533402579888, 0.5, 0.747533402579888, 
0.5, 0.747533402579888, 0.5, 0.747533402579888, 0.5, 0.747533402579888, 
0.5, 0.747533402579888, 0.5, 0.747533402579888, 0.944702130460738, 
0.5, 0.944702130460738, 0.5, 0.944702130460738, 0.5, 0.944702130460738, 
0.5, 0.914667660262252, 0.5, 0.914667660262252, 0.5, 0.914667660262252, 
0.5, 0.914667660262252, 0.5, 0.914667660262252, 0.5, 0.914667660262252, 
0.5, 0.914667660262252, 0.5, 0.914667660262252, 0.944702130460738, 
0.5, 0.944702130460738, 0.5, 0.944702130460738, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 
0.800147952416411, 0.5, 0.800147952416411, 0.5, 0.800147952416411, 
0.5, 0.800147952416411, 0.5, 0.800147952416411, 0.838709717348716, 
0.800147952416411, 0.838709717348716, 0.800147952416411, 0.838709717348716, 
0.800147952416411, 0.838709717348716, 0.800147952416411, 0.838709717348716, 
0.800147952416411, 0.838709717348716, 0.800147952416411, 0.838709717348716, 
0.800147952416411, 0.838709717348716, 0.5, 0.800147952416411, 
0.5, 0.800147952416411, 0.5, 0.800147952416411, 0, 0.451580787792305, 
0, 0.451580787792305, 0, 0.451580787792305, 0, 0.451580787792305, 
0, 0.451580787792305, 0, 0.451580787792305, 0, 0.451580787792305, 
0, 0.451580787792305, 0.5), .Dim = c(203L, 4L)), maximum_points = structure(c(0.5, 
0.419352004803182, 0.419352004803182, 0.419352004803182, 0.419352004803182, 
0.419352004803182, 0.419352004803182, 0.419352004803182, 0.419352004803182, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0353348860019376, 0.0353348860019376, 
0.0353348860019376, 0.0353348860019376, 0.0353348860019376, 0.0353348860019376, 
0.0353348860019376, 0.0353348860019376, 0.5, 0.190285344706225, 
0.190285344706225, 0.0354309314611505, 0.0354309314611505, 0.0354309314611505, 
0.0354309314611505, 0.0354309314611505, 0.0354309314611505, 0.0354309314611505, 
0.0354309314611505, 0.190285344706225, 0.190285344706225, 0.190285344706225, 
0.190285344706225, 0.190285344706225, 0.190285344706225, 0.190285344706225, 
0.190285344706225, 0.190285344706225, 0.190285344706225, 0.190285344706225, 
0.190285344706225, 0.190285344706225, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.222681715801928, 0.222681715801928, 0.222681715801928, 0.222681715801928, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.0968321963495523, 0.0968321963495523, 0.0968321963495523, 
0.0968321963495523, 0.0968321963495523, 0.0968321963495523, 0.0968321963495523, 
0.0968321963495523, 0.5, 0.21505376344086, 0.21505376344086, 
0.21505376344086, 0.21505376344086, 0.21505376344086, 0.21505376344086, 
0.21505376344086, 0.21505376344086, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.865298312421161, 
0.865298312421161, 0.82789108509519, 0.82789108509519, 0.82789108509519, 
0.82789108509519, 0.82789108509519, 0.82789108509519, 0.82789108509519, 
0.82789108509519, 0.865298312421161, 0.865298312421161, 0.865298312421161, 
0.865298312421161, 0.865298312421161, 0.865298312421161, 0.865298312421161, 
0.865298312421161, 0.865298312421161, 0.865298312421161, 0.865298312421161, 
0.865298312421161, 0.865298312421161, 1, 1, 0.913338086705426, 
0.913338086705426, 0.913338086705426, 0.913338086705426, 0.913338086705426, 
0.913338086705426, 0.913338086705426, 0.913338086705426, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.694970507094714, 
0.694970507094714, 0.694970507094714, 0.694970507094714, 0.694970507094714, 
0.694970507094714, 0.694970507094714, 0.694970507094714, 1, 0.929741242956996, 
0.929741242956996, 0.929741242956996, 0.929741242956996, 0.929741242956996, 
0.929741242956996, 0.929741242956996, 0.929741242956996, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.548419213078966, 0.548419213078966, 
0.548419213078966, 0.548419213078966, 0.548419213078966, 0.548419213078966, 
0.548419213078966, 0.548419213078966, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0.5, 0.255374814781996, 0.255374814781996, 0.255374814781996, 
0.255374814781996, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.255374814781996, 0.255374814781996, 
0.255374814781996, 0.255374814781996, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.398483289450429, 
0.398483289450429, 0.398483289450429, 0.398483289450429, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.398483289450429, 0.161290323203977, 0.161290323203977, 
0.161209591513803, 0.161209591513803, 0.161209591513803, 0.161209591513803, 
0.161290323203977, 0.161290323203977, 0.161290323203977, 0.161290323203977, 
0.161209591513803, 0.161209591513803, 0.161209591513803, 0.161209591513803, 
0.161290323203977, 0.161290323203977, 0.161290323203977, 0.161290323203977, 
0.161290323203977, 0.398483289450429, 0.398483289450429, 0.398483289450429, 
0.398483289450429, 0.161290323203977, 0.161290323203977, 0.161290323203977, 
0.161290323203977, 0.398483289450429, 0.398483289450429, 0.398483289450429, 
0.398483289450429, 0.398483289450429, 0.398483289450429, 0.398483289450429, 
0.398483289450429, 0.398483289450429, 0.398483289450429, 0.398483289450429, 
0.398483289450429, 0.398483289450429, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
1, 1, 0.832337120350762, 0.832337120350762, 0.832337120350762, 
0.832337120350762, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.832337120350762, 0.709677419354839, 
0.709677419354839, 0.709677419354839, 0.709677419354839, 0.832337120350762, 
0.832337120350762, 0.832337120350762, 0.832337120350762, 0.709677419354839, 
0.709677419354839, 0.709677419354839, 0.709677419354839, 0.832337120350762, 
0.832337120350762, 0.832337120350762, 0.832337120350762, 0.832337120350762, 
0.832337120350762, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.442671222839882, 0.442671222839882, 
0.283397163276916, 0.283397163276916, 0.283397163276916, 0.283397163276916, 
0.442671222839882, 0.442671222839882, 0.442671222839882, 0.442671222839882, 
0.283397163276916, 0.283397163276916, 0.283397163276916, 0.283397163276916, 
0.442671222839882, 0.442671222839882, 0.442671222839882, 0.442671222839882, 
0.442671222839882, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.442671222839882, 0.442671222839882, 
0.340698528466384, 0.340698528466384, 0.340698528466384, 0.340698528466384, 
0.442671222839882, 0.442671222839882, 0.442671222839882, 0.442671222839882, 
0.340698528466384, 0.340698528466384, 0.340698528466384, 0.340698528466384, 
0.442671222839882, 0.442671222839882, 0.442671222839882, 0.442671222839882, 
0.442671222839882, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.685576901737226, 
0.685576901737226, 0.685576901737226, 0.685576901737226, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0.685576901737226, 0.663570349214972, 0.663570349214972, 
0.663570349214972, 0.663570349214972, 0.685576901737226, 0.685576901737226, 
0.685576901737226, 0.685576901737226, 0.663570349214972, 0.663570349214972, 
0.663570349214972, 0.663570349214972, 0.685576901737226, 0.685576901737226, 
0.685576901737226, 0.685576901737226, 0.685576901737226, 0.685576901737226, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0.669183378958155, 0.669183378958155, 0.669183378958155, 
0.669183378958155, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.669183378958155, 0.669183378958155, 
0.669183378958155, 0.669183378958155, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.379031077580214, 
0.379031077580214, 0.5, 0.5, 0.379031077580214, 0.379031077580214, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.379031077580214, 0.379031077580214, 0.5, 0.5, 0.379031077580214, 
0.379031077580214, 0.5, 0.5, 0.967729256836288, 0.967729256836288, 
1, 1, 0.967729256836288, 0.967729256836288, 1, 1, 0.967729256836288, 
0.826609713837449, 0.826609713837449, 0.967610625409862, 0.967610625409862, 
0.967729256836288, 0.967729256836288, 0.967610625409862, 0.967610625409862, 
0.967729256836288, 0.967729256836288, 0.967610625409862, 0.967610625409862, 
0.967729256836288, 0.967729256836288, 0.967610625409862, 0.967610625409862, 
0.967729256836288, 0.967729256836288, 0.967729256836288, 0.826609713837449, 
0.826609713837449, 0.967729256836288, 0.967729256836288, 0.826609713837449, 
0.826609713837449, 0.967729256836288, 0.967729256836288, 0.826609713837449, 
0.722675196396205, 0.722675196396205, 0.826609713837449, 0.826609713837449, 
0.722675196396205, 0.722675196396205, 0.826609713837449, 0.826609713837449, 
0.967729256836288, 0.967729256836288, 1, 1, 0.967729256836288, 
0.967729256836288, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.897477061307942, 0.897477061307942, 
1, 1, 0.897477061307942, 0.897477061307942, 1, 1, 0.897477061307942, 
0.741935483870968, 0.741935483870968, 0.897477061307942, 0.897477061307942, 
0.741935483870968, 0.741935483870968, 0.897477061307942, 0.897477061307942, 
0.741935483870968, 0.741935483870968, 0.897477061307942, 0.897477061307942, 
0.741935483870968, 0.741935483870968, 0.897477061307942, 0.897477061307942, 
1, 1, 0.897477061307942, 0.897477061307942, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.032538108376287, 
0.032538108376287, 0.0967749770900052, 0.0967749770900052, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.0967749770900052, 0.0967749770900052, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0967749770900052, 
0.0967749770900052, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0967749770900052, 0.0967749770900052, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.032538108376287, 0.032538108376287, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.032538108376287, 0.032538108376287, 0.0647887222047812, 0.0647887222047812, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.0647887222047812, 0.0647887222047812, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0647887222047812, 
0.0647887222047812, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0647887222047812, 0.0647887222047812, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.032538108376287, 0.032538108376287, 0.5, 0.5, 
1, 1, 0.5, 0.322580324979444, 0.322580324979444, 0.5, 0.5, 0.322580324979444, 
0.322580324979444, 0.5, 0.5, 0.322580324979444, 0.106364539814871, 
0.106364539814871, 0.322580324979444, 0.322580324979444, 0.106364539814871, 
0.106364539814871, 0.322580324979444, 0.322580324979444, 0.106364539814871, 
0.106364539814871, 0.322580324979444, 0.322580324979444, 0.106364539814871, 
0.106364539814871, 0.322580324979444, 0.322580324979444, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.322580324979444, 0.322580324979444, 0.5, 0.5, 0.548419212162221, 
0.548419212162221, 1, 1, 0.548419212162221, 0.548419212162221, 
1, 1, 0.548419212162221, 0.548419212162221, 1, 1, 0.548419212162221, 
0.548419212162221, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.526892491080578, 1, 0.526892491080578, 
1, 0.526892491080578, 1, 0.526892491080578, 1, 0.526892491080578, 
1, 0.526892491080578, 1, 0.526892491080578, 1, 0.526892491080578, 
1, 0.0353381808372436, 0.5, 0.0353381808372436, 0.5, 0.0353381808372436, 
0.5, 0.0353381808372436, 0.5, 0.0353381808372436, 0.190286155838143, 
0.5, 0.0354342216918294, 0.190286155838143, 0.0354342216918294, 
0.190286155838143, 0.0354342216918294, 0.190286155838143, 0.0354342216918294, 
0.190286155838143, 0.0354342216918294, 0.190286155838143, 0.0354342216918294, 
0.190286155838143, 0.0354342216918294, 0.190286155838143, 0.0354342216918294, 
0.190286155838143, 0.5, 0.190286155838143, 0.5, 0.190286155838143, 
0.5, 0.190286155838143, 0.5, 0.190286155838143, 0.5, 0.190286155838143, 
0.225826581007251, 0.5, 0.225826581007251, 0.5, 0.225826581007251, 
0.5, 0.225826581007251, 0.5, 0.190286155838143, 0.5, 0.0353381808372436, 
0.5, 0.0353381808372436, 0.5, 0.0353381808372436, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 
1, 0.0967747030398799, 0.5, 0.0967747030398799, 0.5, 0.0967747030398799, 
0.5, 0.0967747030398799, 0.5, 0.0967747030398799, 0.21505376344086, 
0.5, 0.21505376344086, 0.5, 0.21505376344086, 0.5, 0.21505376344086, 
0.5, 0.21505376344086, 0.5, 0.21505376344086, 0.5, 0.21505376344086, 
0.5, 0.21505376344086, 0.5, 0.0967747030398799, 0.5, 0.0967747030398799, 
0.5, 0.0967747030398799, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.944702130460738, 1, 0.747533402579888, 
0.944702130460738, 0.747533402579888, 0.944702130460738, 0.747533402579888, 
0.944702130460738, 0.747533402579888, 0.944702130460738, 0.747533402579888, 
0.944702130460738, 0.747533402579888, 0.944702130460738, 0.747533402579888, 
0.944702130460738, 0.747533402579888, 0.944702130460738, 1, 0.944702130460738, 
1, 0.944702130460738, 1, 0.944702130460738, 1, 0.914667660262252, 
0.944702130460738, 0.914667660262252, 0.944702130460738, 0.914667660262252, 
0.944702130460738, 0.914667660262252, 0.944702130460738, 0.914667660262252, 
0.944702130460738, 0.914667660262252, 0.944702130460738, 0.914667660262252, 
0.944702130460738, 0.914667660262252, 0.944702130460738, 1, 0.944702130460738, 
1, 0.944702130460738, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.800147952416411, 1, 0.800147952416411, 
1, 0.800147952416411, 1, 0.800147952416411, 1, 0.800147952416411, 
0.838709717348716, 1, 0.838709717348716, 1, 0.838709717348716, 
1, 0.838709717348716, 1, 0.838709717348716, 1, 0.838709717348716, 
1, 0.838709717348716, 1, 0.838709717348716, 1, 0.800147952416411, 
1, 0.800147952416411, 1, 0.800147952416411, 1, 0.451580787792305, 
0.5, 0.451580787792305, 0.5, 0.451580787792305, 0.5, 0.451580787792305, 
0.5, 0.451580787792305, 0.5, 0.451580787792305, 0.5, 0.451580787792305, 
0.5, 0.451580787792305, 0.5, 1), .Dim = c(203L, 4L)), weights = structure(c(2.78373149121937e-09, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.73222271931361e-10, 0, 2.48329721429362e-10, 
2.40496282082592e-11, 2.7578656977963e-10, 0, 2.54220850404393e-10, 
4.33892470068574e-11, 1.04762734932699e-11, 3.46967347472702e-10, 
6.62805429888869e-09, 9.71011438457871e-09, 6.66934727401879e-05, 
0.00226860574991657, 0.0245936013080539, 6.56653757206931e-09, 
4.04643481374917e-10, 0.012304847331497, 0.00581222411965193, 
4.15546790866251e-08, 4.63400146191134e-05, 4.57464606155282e-11, 
5.63764656263629e-08, 0, 1.715084053534e-15, 0, 0, 4.63366717510688e-05, 
0.074723822472261, 5.63730975370133e-08, 6.28666542765881e-05, 
1.34986082579289e-15, 3.74987025472652e-05, 0, 0, 0.00823527846911741, 
1.08253324824947e-09, 1.22312848674708e-09, 8.3353867666595e-10, 
9.76129437887468e-10, 0.00581148382808966, 0.00736584714683464, 
0.00823486854272975, 0.000238542754544605, 1.31409294414585e-09, 
8.33727708488548e-10, 2.00337706178445e-09, 0.0189082571457979, 
1.30310708051612e-09, 0.00183505096321415, 0.121407068967736, 
0, 0.0386154821516174, 1.03592199381087e-09, 1.17892176952316e-09, 
9.72574756322812e-09, 3.55612398656478e-08, 0.00227106206106675, 
0.0481664705400131, 6.57696235044834e-09, 1.76408747256683e-08, 
2.86023928536818e-09, 3.08646962272857e-09, 0.10688731033447, 
4.860015547659e-09, 2.47159256403025e-07, 3.13651474452409e-09, 
1.26890031729092e-07, 9.18716948554718e-10, 1.70381865454379e-07, 
0.00233465836083541, 8.75014708650117e-08, 0, 4.75936443906605e-09, 
8.21259017515613e-09, 0.00234975178183373, 5.05773300723426e-09, 
2.02915209626469e-09, 3.78111618480374e-09, 8.74343768372601e-10, 
1.86351476413777e-09, 2.70193808848569e-09, 0.00254745457364861, 
6.39100182122774e-10, 0.000157182877058538, 1.01807899594348e-06, 
0.00232929551283308, 0, 0.000629017545868318, 0, 7.65845474250129e-09, 
0, 0.00157250814153988, 0, 0.000137949021182025, 3.16297573260506e-09, 
0, 0, 0, 0.00226910772522489, 0.00474798846147147, 0.0260205010226886, 
0.0126726751018104, 0.00307558479405289, 0.00410473263922561, 
0.00724196166351907, 0.0161593003395888, 0.00870369261842073, 
0, 5.01399929841213e-09, 4.41780105209752e-09, 0, 0, 3.82283265086342e-09, 
3.36897654382229e-09, 2.68735527471476e-08, 0, 0, 0.000483012313724718, 
0.00142312533277925, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00724483741801811, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00744598129461705, 0.000943426984998133, 0, 0, 
0.00425075290633179, 0.000428939592668569, 0, 0, 0.0117318278240546, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0391190218244746, 0.00226594017501137, 
0.0655235460567518, 0, 0, 0.00259704671622503, 0.0152129028527954, 
0.00353995703073859, 0.0569803624691554, 5.19128541279739e-09, 
3.44886859856599e-09, 0, 0, 0.000643266152424947, 0.0039962189340582, 
0.000789394535340559, 0.0059452725596952, 6.75828695435288e-09, 
5.0032980851673e-09, 0.0120673489739881, 0, 0, 0, 0.027843566985192, 
5.76412766906192e-08, 0.0320944195074327, 0.00554731630605901, 
0, 0.0103508513412659, 4.5707526436107e-09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.20442364072729e-09, 
0, 0.0258045740123558, 4.68979629633854e-09, 0, 0, 0.0707320634886678, 
0, 0), .Dim = 203L))
```

For exemple, for the first box, it goes from `x$minimum_points[1,]` to `x$maximum_points[1,]`. Note that the boxes i propose are a partition of [0,1]^4.

If the dimension of the problem was 2, i could use geom_tile and something like [what this question ends up with](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37626/visualization-of-binned-frequency-distribution-in-r/37660#37660). But i'm in a multidimensional cases, and i wanted a plot that will describe all bivaraite margins with rectangles filled with a quantity of gray proportional to they corresponding weights...

I'm not shure i am clear enough. Could you help ?

Edit : [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814267/variable-size-of-geom-tile-plot?rq=1) might also be related, this looks a lot like what i want, but i want one of these plots for every bivaraite projection of my 4 dimensional problem (something like `pairs` would do if you want to plot 4 dimensional data).

Edit : 
If i want to plot only the first 2 dimensions, i could do something like this :

```
data.frame(xmin = x$minimum_points[,1], 
           ymin = x$minimum_points[,2], 
           xmax = x$maximum_points[,1], 
           ymax = x$maximum_points[,2]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)) + 
  geom_rect(alpha = (x$weight/max(x$weight)))
```

This has an issue : It assumes that the `alpha` parameter is additive : If i set two boxes with respective `alpha` 0.1 and 0.2, the intersection will look like a box with `alpha` 0.3. If this is true, then perfect ! Otherwise something more clever must be done..

Furthermore, how can i facet it up ? I.e do it for all couples if dimensions in a facet_grid ? The cases where each dimension equals itself are not possible so plotting nothing on the diagonal of the facet grid is OK.

Comment: regarding blending of alphas - it unfortunately does not simply "add up". My own previous question might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57394946/set-opacity-of-grey-values-of-overlapping-areas-relative-to-n

Comment: Thanks @Tjebo, helped me a lot. Now i'm looking to change this behavior of ggplot2 (via a simple fork), but i cant find where the alpha blending is in ggplot2 code ;)